# Hacer consulta con Jquery después de cargar una consulta en php

Tags: php, html, jquery

Estoy aprendiendo a crear un chat con php mysql y unos sockets, pero necesito cargar los mensajes anteriores de la base de datos, así que no sé como podría hacerlo.
Resulta que cargo el chatbox con PHP, pero no sé como podría hacer para que una vez cargado el chatbox, se obtenga los mensajes anteriores mediante php. 
Algo como

```
   $(".chatbox").ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
       /*Data, etc*/
       success: function(chats){
         $(this).children(".messages").html(chats);
       }
     })
   })
```

Podría funcionar, pero no estoy seguro e que sea lo correcto, ayuda...

Comment: Aquí la cuestión importante sería precisamente encontrar una forma de consultar a la base de datos para que te traiga los mensajes anteriores de que hablas... Dichos mensajes pueden venir desde el servidor en forma de HTML, o como un JSON el cual deberás parsear en el cliente. El código que muestras me parece que es poco relevante para poder ayudarte, pues el *quid*  de la cuestión es obtener los datos que quieres en el servidor y traerlos en el parámetro `chats` de tu `success`. ¿Cómo obtienes esos datos, bajo qué criterios? Criterios que deberás enviar al servidor para la consulta...

Comment: Yo los obtenía con una consulta php que incluía el html, css todo, digamos solo habia que poner la funcion html() pero no se como hacer que esa consulta se ejecute cuando termine de cargar el chatbox